# AWS ALB to redirect to an URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to use AWS ALB to redirect all the traffic to http URL during any application upgrade.

I have created a default rule which listens to 80 and redirects to S3 URL (http://bucket-name.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:80/index.html). The S3 URL is accessible thru my browser. But when I access the URL that points to ALB the redirection to the S3 URL doesnt work.

Rule Details:

last - HTTP80: default action   - IF  Requests otherwise not routed - 
                                - THEN
Redirect to http://bucket-name.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:80/index.html?#{query}
Status code:HTTP_301

Can anybody help me with this

Comment: what is the error that you get ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to mention `index.html`, just pass the default path where `index.html` is placed inside s3.
[image]

make sure you have set `index` file in your s3.

If you just want some static response, You can also send `HTML` response, you do not need to configure s3.

[image]
Also, make sure there is proper CloudFront integrated with your static website in case of the redirect as I see you redirect to `http`. you can check further [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html)

Comment: Hi Adiii, thanks for sharing the details. It worked.